# Changing color of checkbox object

Tags: java, android

Currently the color of checkbox is blue but I want to disable the check box and change its color to dull grey when a specific condition becomes true. I can't find a way to change the color of the checkbox through its object.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the buttonTint programmaticly when the condition is true..try these lines

```
int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
int colors[] = {color_for_state_checked, color_for_state_normal}
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkbox, new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```

Comment: can you please explain this new object you created ?
 new ColorStateList(states, colors)

Comment: object colors contains the color you defined when the state is checked and the color u defined when the state is not checked, the states object containes the attribute that you want change it's color

Answer (score 0):

Just do implement these two things in your code

**styles.xml**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000</item>   <!-- normal border color change as you wish -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000</item> <!-- activated color change as you wish -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF3F3C</item> <!-- checkbox text color -->
</style>
```

now in your main_activity.xml place below CheckBox code

```
 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check_agree"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:text="I agree"
      android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"/>   <!-- here apply your checkbox style -->
```